# Why does the AWS CLI pip package installation install a six package it can't use?

Tags: pip, aws-cli, six

Whenever I update my AWS CLI with

```
pip install -U awscli
```

it downgrades several packages (`colorama`, `dill`, `rsa`, and `websocket-client`) and upgrades `six` to a version (1.9.0) that it can't use. After updating, if I try to use the AWS CLI, (e.g. `eb status`) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 614, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 627, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 805, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six==1.8.0
```

In order to get the AWS CLIs working again I have to downgrade `six` to 1.8.0 (the other packages can be upgraded to the current versions again without ill effect). But the next update of `awscli` (over the past half dozen or so) always brings the current — but unusable by AWS CLIs — back again.

What's going on here? Is there a bug in the `awscli` package? Have others experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was actually a bug in the `awsebcli` package's setup script that has [now been fixed](https://github.com/gxela/awsebcli/pull/1/files#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298).

Comment: Yes, updating the cli resolved the problem: `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this with the following trick in your userdata script.

```
pip install six==1.8.0
pip install awscli
```

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what "userdata script". And the point is to avoid downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3 installed, use

`pip3 install awscli`